# haskell's autocompletion in vim

Tags: haskell, vim, autocomplete, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

I went through tutorials about how to create vim 
environment with autocomplete words and functions from other modules. And it's fine until I'll change something in my previously created modules. In other files those changes are invisible and vim autocompletes words and functions that doesn't exist anymore and does not help with new functions.

Is there a way to fix this and update ghc-mod data in actually opened files?

Comment: It's rather hard to help you without knowing anything about how you've setup your autocompletion.  There are many possible ways to do what you describe.